# Passing scaled data to x and y axises in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scaling

I've used the following code to visualize the data I have in csv file. I'v scaled the data to dynamically fit within the svg element, but the x and y axises still display the pre-scaled values even that I passed the scale function to both. Does anybody know how to fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>
    .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
        .axis text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 300;
        var padding = 80;
        var dataset = []
        var generateVisualization = function(){
            //Create scale functions
            var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                             .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                             .range([padding, w - padding]);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                             .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                             .range([h - padding, padding]);

            //Define X axis
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                          .scale(xScale)
                          .orient("bottom")
                          .ticks(5);

            //Define Y axis
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                          .scale(yScale)
                          .orient("left")
                          .ticks(5);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

            //Create circles
            svg.append("g")
           .attr("id", "circles")
           .selectAll("circle")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xScale(d[0]);
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return yScale(d[1]);
           })
           .attr("r", 2);

            //Create X axis
            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding + 5) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

            //Create Y axis
            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding - 5) + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis);
        };

        d3.csv("OuputMatrix2.csv", function(error, d) {
            dataset = d.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x"], +d["y"] ]; 
            });
            generateVisualization();});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is a screenshot of the output:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2th83r4r42nn4el/Screenshot%202014-11-11%2015.45.55.png?dl=0

Comment: Well the axes show what the displayed values correspond to. Do you want them to show the coordinates?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I transformed the values to a positive range, so I was expecting the axes to show the coordinates based on the new range starting from 0 to the maximum value in the range. Does it make sense?

Comment: The output range corresponds to screen coordinates. That is, the scales are mapping your input data to screen coordinates where it should be drawn. If you want to show those values on the axies, you need to define separate scales for them.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff But there are negative values. I've displayed the scaled data and there are no such values. I checked some examples and they always used the same scale that they used to plot the points http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000002001/ch01.html#_10_scatterplot_html .. I'm kinda lost -_-"

Comment: The negative values on the axes mean that there are negative values in your data.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you.. I could not solve it so, I git rid of the coordinates since they are not really important for my purpose.